# how to set position for button in cardview

Tags: java, android, button, cardview

I have a few button in cardview but i can't drag it to anywhere i want.
in fact i want set , "next" button of media player to right of "play" button .

this is my xml code :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:cardElevation="12dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:background="@mipmap/play" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/next"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@mipmap/previous"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"/>

        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
            android:max="100"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

it's result :

[pic result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEFtA.png)

and what i want is :

[what i want image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWZzi.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        app:cardElevation="12dp">

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@mipmap/next"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/play" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/previous"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
        android:max="100"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: thank you , your idea (use of `linerlayout`) and (use of `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"`) very helped me !

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party. Alternatively, you can try `GridLayout`. Here is an example of using `GridLayout` which I used in my example.

`android:layout_row` defines which row should it be. Row number starts from top to bottom.
`android:layout_column` defines which column the object should be. Left to right ordering.
`android:layout_columnSpan` defines how many columns should the object be.

> ```
>     <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
>         android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/card_marginBottom">
>
>         <GridLayout
>             style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content">
>
>             <ImageView
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:src="@drawable/sample"
>                 android:layout_row="0"
>                 android:layout_column="0" />
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/txtVw_RestName"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
>                 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
>                 android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
>                 android:layout_row="0"
>                 android:layout_column="1"
>                 android:layout_columnSpan="2"/>
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/txtVw_RestLot"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
>                 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
>                 android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
>
>                 android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
>
>                 android:layout_row="1"
>                 android:layout_column="1"
>                 android:layout_columnSpan="2"/>
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/txtVw_DescProgBar"
>                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:text="Vacancy"
>
>                 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
>                 android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
>
>                 android:layout_row="2"
>                 android:layout_column="1" />
>
>             <ProgressBar
>                 android:id="@+id/progBar"
>                 android:layout_width="150dp"
>                 android:minHeight="5dp"
>                 android:max="100"
>                 style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
>
>                 android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
>                 android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
>                 android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
>
>                 android:layout_row="2"
>                 android:layout_column="2"/>
>         </GridLayout>
>     </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Add any type of layout in your cardview and then add your elements (Button, TextView...) in the layout.

[Design appearance of following xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTZQo.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cardview_provider"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

    <!-- 
        //Layout within the cardview in which you have to add your components
        //(Button, TextView...)
        //could be other type of layout (I usually use ConstraintLayout)
    -->
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/provider_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/provider_name"
            android:text="Google"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/provider_icon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/provider_uri"
            android:text="https://www.google.com"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/provider_icon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/provider_name"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and explain exactly how to add the layouts you mention.  One or two code examples would be welcome.